# show to company name in customer register form magento2 and edit form get the data

Tags: magento2

> I need to show to the company name in the customer registration form
> magento2 and I want to add in the name.phtml file and get the data
> into the form

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below code

1. Copy file from vendor\magento\module-customer\view\frontend\templates\widget\name.phtml  to
   your theme file (Override this file in your module or Theme)
2. Open the name.phtml file after add below code

   ```
        $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company::class);
        if ($_company->isEnabled()): 
            echo $_company->setCompany($block->getFormData()->getCompany())->toHtml(); 
        endif;
   ```